# Scala worksheet not importing sbt dependencies

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I have the latest version of Eclipse installed.

Error - The eclipse scala worksheet fails to recognise imported packages via sbt.

I am opening the project via the File -> Open function of the Eclipse header bar. I am importing packages via sbt but when running the REPL via the scala worksheet, the worksheet fails to recognise those dependencies and throws errors on the lines where those packages are being used.

Yes I am importing the dependencies in the worksheet as well as - `import x._`

Question - Is scala worksheet independent of the project currently open?

Note - I am not using the SBT IDE, but manually installing Eclipse separately with the scala plugin.

Comment: Give a little more detail like what kind of error is eclipse throwing.

Comment: It is unable to recognise the imported packages.